# How to export to Milkshape 3D file

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I open an existing Blender file in blender and I can't export to [Milkshape 3D](http://www.milkshape3d.com/). The option is there under exports but it is greyed out. Why is this?

Comment: Could you add a few screen shots?

Comment: I think you mean MilkShape3d. It's grayed out for me, if I select a non mesh object. Select the Mesh you lilke to export and try it again.